# How to send data to the same application installed on other android device using wifi

Tags: java, android

i have an application on my android device like "A" and same application installed on the other android device like "B", now i want to send data from app "A" to app "B" using WIFI service. so please suggest me how can i implement this feature.

i tried many times to get help from google but all is vain.
it is possible from WIFI direct or NFC.

Comment: The most appropriate way is to use GCM & GCM Receiver

Comment: yes i have that option also, but i want to implement this feature on wifi only, because using wifi user can communicate without having internet..

Comment: A direct `Socket` connection would work, if at least one device is not firewalled and the other device has a mechanism for discovering its IP address.  You may want to have a read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) for that.  GCM is also an option, but generally not if you're trying for a peer-to-peer connection between the devices (which it sounds like you are).

Comment: yeah set the condition that when wifi is available sync the data to other device using Gcm, your second device will receive the notification through broadcast receiver

Comment: ok dear @aroth i have the ip address, SSID and all of the information of the child device ("B"), according to your answer i can send the data using peer-to-peer connection, but how my application will come to know that the data is only for my application. do i need to use the android service.

Comment: Using the built-in network-service discovery API will yelp with that, yes.  You'll also want to implement your communications protocol in a way that rejects spurious connection attempts (for instance, by requiring a complex/cryptographically secure handshake).  And if you're really concerned that some of your data may be intercepted, consider encrypting the entire exchange.

Comment: thanks @aroth your answer is very helpful. i read the documentation of the network service API, it' covered my requirement. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple p2p architecture.

You will need to use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and a pair of streams that works with the kind of data you need to send, like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

On sender side:

```
Socket s = new Socket(IP,PORT);
s.connect();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
dos.write("hello".toByteArray());
```

Then on receiver side:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket s = ss.accept(); //This call will block execution, use separate thread
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream);
byte[] data = dis.read();
```

With this you can send and receive bytes, just use the stream that works with your data type.

Of course, once connection is established, both clients could send/write, just make the appropiate Input/Output Stream.

Hope this helps.

Comment: accept the answer if it has solved your question please.